# How to call a function from a different swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have multiple swift files of type UIViewController in my Xcode 6 beta-2 project.

I basically want to know some data from file A to use in file B.

My files are both UIViewControllers, and I have created a function with no parameters which returns a string in UIViewController_A. When I try and call said function in UIViewController_B, intellisense fills it out for me but says I have to have a parameter which autofills as UIViewController_A).

In the code, LoginScreen.swift == ViewController_A, and ViewResidentsTask == ViewController_B.

My function is called checkPrivs, exists in LoginScreen.swift and looks like this:

```
func checkPrivs()-> String{
    return userPrivType
}
```

this is how I think it should be called:

```
var userType = LoginScreen.checkPrivs()
```

this is what intellisense does when I try and call it:

```
var userType = LoginScreen.checkPrivs(LoginScreen)
```

This throws up an error saying "Expected ',' seperator"
Not really sure what I should be replacing LoginScreen with but everything I've tried (empty, string, current file name) throws up an error.

Comment: your `checkPrivs()` is an _instance_ method not a _class_ one, so you need to call it as _instance_ method should be called.

Comment: I have the book, but to somebody who's still learning programming it's not a simple case of opening it and finding the answer.

Comment: @holex thanks for clearing that up, that sort of pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 12):

You should create instance of LoginScreen first and call method on that object:

```
let login = LoginScreen()
var userType = login.checkPrivs()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Super simple answer - all you have to do is initialize the view controller with () like this:

```
var userType = LoginScreen().checkPrivs()
```

This is working for me as of 5/11/17 in the newest version of Xcode & Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It’s simple! Just put “public” before “Func”
`Public func sayhi(){ Print(“hi”) }`

Although this doesn’t work in all places.
Try it out in a playground first to understand!